# Working with data in mongo

Tags: mongodb

I need help to get a best form to do a specific query in a Mongodb

I have a jobs collection being fed hourly, and want take some useful information:

- The last 10 record by jobname and take a avg the timedur but remove the higher and lower value.
- I can get 10 last records by timeend key

Thanks for helping me solve this problem.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("52446679e4b0961fd47b63a9"),
"jobname" : "ftp_s_jobx",
"descript" : "Get some file",
"applic" : "PRD.TEAM",
"applgroup" : "bil.jobx.set",
"schedtab" : "bil.jobx.set",
"owner" : "cdfiles",
"runcount" : "1",
"cyclic" : "Y",
"times" : [
    {
        "timeelep" : "3674"
    },
    {
        "timestmp" : "20130926132537"
    },
    {
        "timedur" : "00:00:36"
    },
    {
        "timeend" : "26/09/2013 13:25:37"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: what is the query you want to run?

Comment: Hay Sangram, I need to calculate a average the timedur key by jobname, but, for I calculate the average I need only last 10 records by jobname( I take this by timeend key),and remove the higher and lower value (timedur ) from this 10 record  ... This I want to compare with the last value (timedur). If last run is greater than the average, then raise an alert. tks for help